# jQuery XML request: is there a way to make it work locally?

Tags: jquery, xml

I read some questions about XML requests and that it won't work using file:/// protocol. Now I store XML data in variables and use jQuery to parse them, like this:

```
xml = "<language><title>TITLE</title></language>";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
```

Is there a way to parse an XML file locally without using cross-origin requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a local web server like [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/). Using the `file` protocol will not work with ajax requests.

Comment: I'm using cordova for a mobile app. I tried moving the xml file in xampp but it will still request using file protocol. Should I put the project files where xampp server files are located ('htdocs' folder)?

Comment: yes, they need to be under `htdocs`. Check your xampp client, it should be running apache under port 80. In your browser type `http://localhost/[SITE_FOLDER]`

Comment: It now works, thanks. Unfortunately, I get a 'loading' text at the bottom of the page and some page elements aren't positioned like before.

Comment: Solved. I found out I had a very old version of cordova and updating it made the app work fine.